# where is full name stored in sql forms db

Tags: forms-authentication

We use FBA and currently have 500+ FBA users, we also use the FBA management pack from CodePlex. New user requests come in all the time for new users and adding users to roles. The issue our helpdesk face's is that the users already exist or are already in the role the end user has requested. This results in our helpdesk spending a great deal of time searching the name and then clicking within the users account and scrolling down all the roles to see if the tick box is ticked. When you have 40 to check it takes a long time. I have created a page using external content types and have made it so end users can now search themselves to see if the account or role is created\added. The only thing I am missing is the Full Name field\column! I cannot see it in any of the tables in the FBA DB. Where is this stored? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value for Full Name is not stored within the Membership Database, per the solution [`SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack`](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/). The value of Full Name is used to add the user, once created in the `aspnetdb`, to the SharePoint site itself.

`/// <summary>
        /// Adds a user to the SharePoint (in no particular group)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="login"></param>
        /// <param name="email"></param>
        /// <param name="fullname"></param>
        private void AddUserToSite(string login, string email, string fullname)
        {
            this.Web.AllUsers.Add(
                login,
                email,
                fullname,
                "");
        }`

You may want to use a `Stored Procedure` on the `aspnetdb` to query for the value.

`Use [aspnetdb]
EXEC dbo.aspnet_UsersInRole_IsUserInRole @ApplicationName = '/', @UserName = 'janedoe@company.com', @RoleName = 'MyRole'`

You will need to adjust the values, and the `Application Name` can be found in the `web.config` of the SharePoint Web Application under the `roles/provider` element.

Comment: Also, if you'd like to retrieve the full name from SharePoint, you can see the code here to see how it is done: https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Layouts/FBA/MANAGEMENT/UserEdit.aspx.cs